# Mocked method still called

Tags: java, mockito

I have mocked a public String method:

```
Mockito.when(SomeClass.staticMethod(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(ArrayNode.class), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(JSON_RESULT);
```

This method contains in its instructions a static method call named `staticMethod`, coming from a different class.

When running my test, `staticMethod` is called where it shouldn't. Why? I just want to return a `String` when `someMethod` is called. The fact that it's entering inside it and calling `staticMethod` makes it break the code (because `staticMethod` uses a path to dig a `File`, which it doesn't know in Unit Testing)

EDIT: I'm running a test of a Service that gets a SQL File content (`File` classes), executes a query (using `Daos` classes) and retrieves a `JSON` string.

One of the method is getting a File (using a static method from another class), processes it, and returns a String. I mocked this method in order to return my own `JSON` string.

But it still enters the method tries to get the File, process it, etc.. Since I'm in a Unit Testing environment, I don't have access to everything, hence the `NullException` error I'm getting when the static method is called.

Why is it still entering the method despite being mocked?

Comment: Could you add the full code of what you are trying to test?

Comment: Is `someClass` final or private? Is `someClass.someMethod` final or private? Is `someClass` a spy?

Comment: see updated post.
@durron597: someClass is final local variable that is mocked in my test method. Could it be because it's local?

Comment: I was asking those questions about the class definition itself, not about the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why it wasn't working : the class I was mocking was used as a local variable whereas it should have been declared in the class variables.